# Do the UFOs over the continents get removed when they raise the terror level?

Tags: xcom

Each round, during the Timed Phase, UFOs can wind up overflying various continental landmasses.  Each UFO that is not shot down by the intrepid forces directed by the Commander raises the terror level.  Do these UFOs then get removed, or do they persist (potentially raising the terror level again) into future turns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UFOs will remain over the continent, provided the continent's panic level has not reached orange (panic).  Once the panic level reaches orange, all UFOs over that continent are moved to orbit.

According to the electronic rules ([Download the app](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/products/xcom-the-board-game/) -> Menu -> Rules -> UFOS) or the [Rules Reference](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/54/ec/54ec74ce-1584-4354-9677-7fe1b1085b08/xcom_rules_reference.pdf) p11:

> If a continent has fallen into panic when updating the panic levels in the app, all UFOs in that continent are added to orbit.

Also as it has in the electronic FAQ ([app](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/products/xcom-the-board-game/) -> Menu -> FAQ):

> Q: Do UFOs remain on the board after increasing panic?
>   A: Yes, UFOs remain on the board until destroyed.

Comment: Please add links to these electronic sources if possible. (+1 anyway - looks like a thorough answer)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Hopefully it is easier to find now.

Comment: Thanks! I've reformatted your links and quotes - feel free to change it back if you don't like it.

Answer (score 1):

They persist into future turns and can raise the terror level again.

In terms of strategy, one of the key cards is the one that lets you use satellites to pull UFOs into orbit.  It is far more efficient to pull most of the UFOs into orbit, and fight them with a bunch of satellites, rather than trying to spread interceptors out over all the continents.  Not only can a few satellites handle a large number of UFOs, but if they are lost, you only lose them for one turn and then automatically get them back.  You shouldn't have UFOs piling up over the continents until you're getting ready to do the final mission.